# Magento 2 - Translate Cancel Button

Tags: magento2, localisation

The Javascript translation in Magento 2 is buggy as hell. And I just can't get the cancel button for the minicart dialogue translated. The one when you try to delete a product from the cart. I even tried adding it manually to the js-translation.json but that does not work either. Any tips?

Comment: hi, did you find any solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I could not find a good solution :( I think I hacked something stupid together but can't remember exactly. But it still seems buggy as hell.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across the fix which should be released in 2.3.*

A temporary fix is to override the confirm.js file in your theme and make the changes specified in [the PR](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/17359/files).

To override in your theme place the new file in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Ui/web/js/confirm.js`